# How to implement a variadic tuple_map operation?

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++14

I want to implement a function which maps a variadic list of tuples to another tuple, given a function.

It applies an N-ary function `f` to a list of elements taken from a list of N tuples (each with size at least M) and creates a new M-element tuple from the result of these applications.

For a list of N tuples, each with M elements, the call to `std::make_tuple` would look like this pseudocode:

```
std::make_tuple(
  f(t1_1, t2_1, t3_1, ..., tN_1),
  f(t1_2, t2_2, t3_2, ..., tN_2),
  f(t1_3, t2_3, t3_3, ..., tN_3),
  ...
  f(t1_M, t2_M, t3_M, ..., tN_M)
)
```

Sometimes this operation is named `zipWith` in other languages.

I want this function, `tuple_map`, to have the following signature:

```
template<class Tuple1, class... Tuples2, class Function>
auto tuple_map(Tuple1&& tuple1, Tuples&&... tuples, Function f);
```

I've figured out the implementation for a function taking a single tuple:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <integer_sequence>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class Tuple, class Function, size_t... I>
auto tuple_map_impl(Tuple&& t, Function f, std::index_sequence<I...>)
  -> decltype(
       std::make_tuple(
         f(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...
       )
     )
{
  return std::make_tuple(
    f(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...
  );
}

template<class Tuple, class Function>
auto tuple_map(Tuple&& t, Function f)
  -> decltype(
       tuple_map_impl(
         std::forward<Tuple>(t),
         f,
         std::make_index_sequence<
           std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value
         >()
       )
     )
{
  using indices = std::make_index_sequence<
    std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value
  >;
  return tuple_map_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(t), indices());
}
```

When I introduce another parameter pack (`Tuples`) in addition to `I...`, it causes problems:

```
template<class Tuple1, class... Tuples, class Function, size_t... I>
auto tuple_map_impl(Tuple1&& tuple1, Tuples&&... tuples, Function f, std::index_sequence<I...>)
  -> decltype(
       std::make_tuple(
         f(
           std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple1>(t1)),
           std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples))...
         )...
       )
     )
{
  return std::make_tuple(
    f(
      std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)),
      std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples))...
    )...
  );
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding ‘get<I>(forward<Tuples>(tuples))’
```

This is because I've used two packs with different lengths (`I` and `Tuples`) within the same expression.

I can't think of a different way to write this function which would not use the two packs within the same expression.

What is the best way to implement `tuple_map`?

Comment: Can you give a complete specification first, saying what the function is *supposed* to do?

Comment: According to an accepted answer, actually you wanted a function that *applies an `N`-ary function f to a list of elements taken from a list of `N` tuples (each with size `M`) and creates a new `M`-element tuple from the result of these applications.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this code seems to do the trick with Visual Studio 2013 (November 2013 CTP):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

// index_sequence implementation since VS2013 doesn't have it yet
template <size_t... Ints> class index_sequence {
public:
  static size_t size() { return sizeof...(Ints); }
};

template <size_t Start, typename Indices, size_t End>
struct make_index_sequence_impl;

template <size_t Start, size_t... Indices, size_t End>
struct make_index_sequence_impl<Start, index_sequence<Indices...>, End> {
  typedef typename make_index_sequence_impl<
      Start + 1, index_sequence<Indices..., Start>, End>::type type;
};

template <size_t End, size_t... Indices>
struct make_index_sequence_impl<End, index_sequence<Indices...>, End> {
  typedef index_sequence<Indices...> type;
};

template <size_t N>
using make_index_sequence =
    typename make_index_sequence_impl<0, index_sequence<>, N>::type;

// The code that actually implements tuple_map
template <size_t I, typename F, typename... Tuples>
auto tuple_zip_invoke(F f, const Tuples &... ts) {
  return f(get<I>(ts)...);
}

template <typename F, size_t... Is, typename... Tuples>
auto tuple_map_impl(F f, index_sequence<Is...>, const Tuples &... ts) {
  return make_tuple(tuple_zip_invoke<Is>(f, ts...)...);
}

template <typename F, typename Tuple, typename... Tuples>
auto tuple_map(F f, const Tuple &t, const Tuples &... ts) {
  return tuple_map_impl(f, make_index_sequence<tuple_size<Tuple>::value>(), t,
                        ts...);
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c) { return a + b + c; }

int main() {
  auto res =
      tuple_map(sum, make_tuple(1, 4), make_tuple(2, 5), make_tuple(3, 6));
  cout << "(" << get<0>(res) << ", " << get<1>(res) << ")\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
(6, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might approach this problem by factoring the mapping and the catting. Using your existing `tuple_map`, try this:

```
template <typename ...Tuple, typename F>
auto tuple_map(Tuple && tuple, F f)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(tuple_map(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), f)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion and `std::tuple_cat()` like this:

```
template <class Function, class Tuple, size_t... I>
auto tuple_map_impl(Function f, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)))...);
}

template <class F, class Tuple, class... Tuples>
auto tuple_map(F f, Tuple&& t, Tuples&&... tuples)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(tuple_map_impl(f, std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>{}),
                          tuple_map(f, tuples...));
}

template <class F>
auto tuple_map(F) { return std::make_tuple(); }
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/035286293ddf962b)**</kbd>